# How to cancel sortable for both header and content in portlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to cancel sortable portlet option for two div classes.I have tried below coding,

**My Div:**

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="portlet>
       <div class="portlet-header 
       <div class="portlet-content">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Tried to cancel sortable:**

```
$( ".column").sortable( "option", "cancel", '.portlet-header');    
$( ".column").sortable( "option", "cancel", '.portlet-content');
```

It doesn't cancel sortable for both header and content.But if i cancel header only, it cancels otherwise if cancel content only, it cancels propely. I want to make cancel sortable for both.How to cancel for both header and content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(".column").sortable("option", "cancel", ".portlet-header, .portlet-content");
```

This code Works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".column").sortable("option", "cancel", ".portlet-header, .portlet-content");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         $( ".column" ).sortable({
            items: "div:not(.portlet-header,.portlet-content)"
        });
```

check you html as well, at least it looks invalid :

```
<div class="portlet-header
```

*'>' is missing*

```
<div class="portlet-header">
```